# Row & col class they dont adjust acording to the screen size

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to move the div inside the row & col class according to the screen size but my div just remains fixed and it doesn't adjust. Even though I don't put any kind of positioning to the divs inside the row it should move. My other pages work properly, but I can`t make this working.

Why is this happening?

My code:

```css
.my-posted-jobs {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 101px;
  width: 44em;
  left: 11em;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1.my-posted-jobs-title {
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.my-jobs-section {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.separate-job {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 9px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -5px rgba(21, 89, 211, 0.54);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -5px rgba(21, 89, 211, 0.54);
  height: 13em;
  -webkit-animation: appear 1s ease 0s 1 normal;
  -moz-animation: appear 1s ease 0s 1 normal;
  -ms-animation: appear 1s ease 0s 1 normal;
  animation: appear 1s ease 0s 1 normal;
  position: relative;
}

.pictures-li {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  right: 6em;
  position: absolute;
}

.job-date-li {
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<section class="my-posted-jobs">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <h1 class="my-posted-jobs-title">@ViewBag.myJobsTitle</h1>
      <div class="border-job"></div>

      <ul class="my-jobs-section">

        <li class="separate-job">
          <div class="content-li">

            <h2 class="content-li--headline"></h2>

            <div class="pictures-li">

              <img class="posted-pic" ..>

            </div>

            <div class="job-date-li">

              here is some date.
            </div>

          </div>

        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things I noticed off the bat.  Right now, you're using EMs hardcoded to dictate the size of the block.  That'll cause that component to not be responsive. Here's a possible solution:

```
/* Setting a max-width of 44em while keeping the width as 100% makes it responsive. Remove the LEFT, which causes the section to offset at a fixed 11em. */

.my-posted-jobs {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 101px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 44em;
 }
```

Since you're using Bootstrap 3, use that to your advantage.  The offset cols can help with the 'left' attribute in a better responsive way.  Read this part of the documentation:

[Offset Columns Documentation - Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting)

Happy Coding!